# What are the cheapest licenses for Windows Server (current) which I can legally run

Tags: licensing, windows

1) A Web server

2) A Server running MySQL

Please list any technical limitations, if you know them (e.g. max memory).

Thank you

Comment: If all you need is a webserver and a platform for MySQL, there are lots free OS to chose from (Linux, *BSD) - but the 2 programs are rarely found in combination without a scripting language - this may be more of an issue.

Comment: @symcbean: We need windows on the webserver.  Could use linux etc. on the DB box, but don't have any linux skilz I'm afriad ;) So don't want to mix platforms.

Answer (score 2):

1: Windows Server Web Edition under SPLA - about 15 USD per month.

2: the same ;)

Technical limitations - I assume you are smart enough to find micrsoft's website and there the website of Windows.

Comment: Thanks.  Current name seems to be "Windows Web Server 2008". Can't find any technical limitations compared to standard edition - which seems rather strange!

Comment: @SSS - there are a lot of limitations regarding which services you can install on the OS. You can't make it a domain controller, install DHCP, Hyper-V,ADLDS,RDS,WSUS, etc. See the differences [here](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/r2-compare-roles.aspx) and [here](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/r2-differentiated-features.aspx) and [here](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/r2-compare-specs.aspx) - this last one reallllly shows the difference in Web edition to the rest.

Comment: @Farseeker - looks like the only one that would cause a problem for us is lack of MSMQ.  What a thing to leave of a web server! Even desktop versions have it.  Presumably you could still utilise MSMQ on another machine?  I will have to look into this.

Comment: @SSS - afraid I've no idea, I've never had any reason to use MSMQ specifically. That said, all our web servers run 2008 Standard.

Comment: Same here - never used MSMQ. Note that if you need message queueing, you can ALSO use SQL SERVER SERVICE BROKER - does the same thing within SQL Server.